# Titanium tableView, text is gray in android by default, is there a way to change this?

Tags: uitableview, titanium, tableview

Is there a way to change colors of Titanium tableviews?

I am selecting a tableview from a SQLite database. In the android emulator,  the tableview row text is gray on a white background.

Also, how can I add labels to the rows with the title pulled from the database.

CODE:

```
var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({ editable:true });
var db = Titanium.Database.install('baza1.sqlite', 'baza1.sqlite');
var sql = db.execute('SELECT * FROM vels GROUP BY name');
var data = [];
while(sql.isValidRow()) {
    var ime = sql.fieldByName('name');
    var mID = sql.fieldByName('id');
    data.push({ title:ime, hasChild:true, id:mID, url:'opis.js' });
    sql.next();
}

tableview.setData(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create [tableViewRow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow) and push it to your data array. You can simply customize the tableViewRow. Try the code below instead of `data.push({ title:ime, hasChild:true, id:mID, url:'opis.js' });`

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title:ime,
     hasChild:true,
     id:mID,
     url:'opis.js',
     color : 'blue',
     backgroundColor : 'black'
});
data.push(row);
```

Comment: Thanks you Anand, your code did not help me directly ( i probably did something wrong :D ), but it did give me an idea i went blindly and pushed color:'black' together with the rest of the data to the array, and it is working, all thanks to you :D.